# c++ template non-type argument lambda function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

This works:

```
#include <functional>

template < bool (*F)( int ) > class Foo {};

bool fooFunc( int n ) { return true; }

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    auto a = Foo< fooFunc >();
}
```

but this doesn't work, because you can't convert the lambda to a function pointer:

```
#include <functional>

template < bool (*F)( int ) > class Foo {};

auto barFunc = [] ( int n ) -> bool { return true; };

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    auto a = Foo< barFunc >();
}
```

and this doesn't work, because you can't use a std::function<> as a template non-type parameter:

```
#include <functional>

template < std::function< bool( int ) > F > class Bar {};

auto barFunc = [] ( int n ) -> bool { return true; };

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    auto b = Bar< barFunc >();
}
```

So how do I create a template class that is able to accept a lambda enclosure as a template non-type parameter?

Comment: Note sure what you mean by non-type template parameter. Do you mean not simply putting `template <typename T>`? Is it because doing so relaxes the template parameter requirements too much for your needs?

Comment: He means a **value** (as opposed to a type) template parameter, e.g.: `template <int N>`

Comment: I think you are trying to do something at compile-time that can't be done in the general case until run-time, which is why "you can't use a std::function<> as a template non-type parameter"

Comment: If conversion from `[](int)->bool` to `bool(*)(int)` was `constexpr`, this would be easy to do.

Comment: To be clear, if the standard had said "The closure type for a lambda-expression with no lambda-capture has a public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion function to pointer to function having the same parameter and return types as the closure type’s function call operator." *`constexpr`* instead of *`const`* this would be doable.  But the standard was conservative.  I cannot think of a technical reason why that conversion shouldn't be *`constexpr`*, can anyone else?

Comment: @Yakk Lambda expressions aren't valid constant expressions -- in that same vein, to mark a member function `constexpr`, the class type has to be a literal type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create a class template with a type parameter, and use `decltype` to deduce the type of the lambda when you instantiate the template.

```
#include <functional>

template <typename Function> 
class Bar 
{ };

auto barFunc = [] ( int n ) -> bool { return true; };

int main()
{
    auto b = Bar<decltype(barFunc)>();
}
```

But note that lambdas are not default constructible, so you'll probably need to add more code to create a constructor of `Bar` that takes in a copy of the lambda:

```
template <typename Function> 
class Bar 
{ 
    public:

    Bar(Function f) : m_function(f)
    { }

    private:

    Function m_function;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you need to add a pointer because the function did not decay into one.

```
int main( int argc, char** )
{
    auto a = Foo< std::add_pointer<decltype(fooFunc)>::type(0) >();
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Why is the `(0)` needed in `std::add_pointer<decltype(fooFunc)>::type(0)`?